# I need to count the number of different rows a word appears in

Tags: postgresql, count

So far I have

```
SELECT
    word, count(*)
FROM
    (SELECT
            regexp_split_to_table(ColDescription, '\s') as word
    FROM tblCollection
    ) a
GROUP BY word
ORDER BY count(*) desc
```

Which makes a nice list of all of the words and how many times they appear throughout my Description column.

What I need is a way to also display how many times a word is in a row at least once.

For example, if my data was:

```
hello hello test 
hello test test test
test hi
```

it would show

```
word    count   # of rows it appears in
hello     3        2
test      5        3
hi        1        1
```

I'm very much a beginner with databases, any help is appreciated!

A sample table:

```
CREATE TABLE tblCollection ( ColDescription varchar(500) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY);
```

The sample data is:

```
"hello hello test"
"hello test test test"
"test hi"
```

Each string being its own row.

Comment: give `create table` and _sample data_

Comment: I added some info I hope that is more clear

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main obstacle is that your subquery doesn't preserve any information about where it found each instance of a word. This is easily fixed:

```
SELECT
  regexp_split_to_table(ColDescription, '\s') as word,
  ColDescription
FROM tblCollection
```

Now you've got the source field listed along with each word, and it's just a matter of counting them:

```
SELECT
  word, count(*), count(distinct ColDescription)
FROM
...
```

Comment: This is perfect! I've spent hours trying to figure this out. Thanks!